# Can we have blocking waits in onDestroy()?

Tags: android, ondestroy

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which listens for an intent in onDestroy() callback. And there is a blocking while which goes on till bluetooth discoverability is switched off. Once discoverability is off, the `changeModeReceiver` will call its `onReceive()` and set destroy_ok to true, and hence breaking out of the while loop. But, this is not giving desired results.

- Toast message, "In onDestroy()" is not getting printed
- "In onDestroy()" is getting printed in the logcat
- The bluetooth is still switched on

The code is as follows.

```
boolean destroy_ok = false;

protected void onDestroy(){ 

    System.out.println("In onDestroy()");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    BroadcastReceiver changeModeReceiver  = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
            String mode = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE);
            if (mode.equals(BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE))
                destroy_ok = true;
        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver (changeModeReceiver, filter);

    Intent discoverableIntent = new
    Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,1);
    startActivity(discoverableIntent);

    while (!destroy_ok){}

    unregisterReceiver(changeModeReceiver);

    BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if (adapter.isEnabled())
        adapter.disable();

    System.out.println("Leaving onDestroy()");

    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Comment: You can't predict when `onDestroy()` will be called.

Comment: But, in this particular case, it's getting called as expected and desired. "In onDestroy()" is showing up in logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onDestroy` method (as well as all other activity lifecycle methods, view callback methods, etc.) is called on the application's main UI thread, so no, you shouldn't block for a significant period of time when called. Doing so will likely result in lag, and may even spawn an ANR (application not responding) error if you block for more than 5-10 seconds.

Comment: I understand. But can you pinpoint what's wrong with the above code. The wait happens for approximately one second.

Comment: The problem is the "spin loop" you have in your code: `while (!destroy_ok){}`. While waiting for the `!destroy_ok` condition to be satisfied, the program will iterate through the empty while loop at lightning speed... since each iteration corresponds to an instruction that the processor will have to execute, the empty while loop will likely eat up a significant portion of the CPU. The decrease in available CPU will likely slow down other threads running in your application as a result.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving
>   data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content
>   provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here. This method is usually
>   implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an
>   activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things
>   around while the rest of its application is still running. There are
>   situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting
>   process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it
>   should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29)

So simply said, use onPause() for such operations. Also, I would use a `Service` or a new `Thread` in your case.

Comment: But onPause() would get called more frequently. The job that I have to do has to be done only once. For example, onPause() would be called even when a dialog box comes up asking if the bluetooth could be switched on. This is the best method I could come up with, to make bluetooth undiscoverable on exiting the app.